# Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see similar questions in this field but my question is different from these as i don't set state directly from this.state .
my code is

```
state = {
count: 0};

handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: ++this.state.count });
};
```

as you see i don't set state directly but given me this error at this line

Comment: `++this.state.count` this modifies the state, though.

Comment: hello @vlaz if i dont use this notation ; what i use ?

Comment: @SeyyedMahdiyarZerehpoush I've answered that.

Comment: Also as a rule of thumb, you shouldn't use this.state in setState.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
++this.state.count
```

This tries to mutate the state directly, because you're trying to do this:

```
this.state.count = this.state.count + 1
```

which changes the current value of state, but you should do this using setState not directly as the error says.

Do this instead:

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
```

As a best practice, [use a callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to avoid a race condition, such as:

```
this.setState(prev => {
    return {
        count: prev.count + 1,
    };
});
```

Comment: Warning: state updates happen asynchronously, so referencing `this.state` in what you pass to `setState` can cause data races. Better to pass a function that takes a `prevState` argument.

Comment: @JosephSible yeah I know, but the question is not regarding that. The question is about mutating state directly. I'll update tho.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't mutate the state directly you can do as follows.

```
   this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count+1;
    }));
```

Comment: i'm confused . whats the difference between your answer and 2 other answers ?

Comment: No significant difference in this context. 
You might want to read this. https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c

Comment: This answer is the best. When updating the state to a value that depends on a previous state, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can functionally update the state, therefore it takes the previous value of state, the props you are passing it and calculates the next state like so:

```
handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState((state, props) => {
     return {
      count: state.count + 1
     }
    });
};
```